# Keystore Tampered With or Wrong Password

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, keystore

I am trying to make a signed apk in android studio on a machine that I did not originally create the keystore file on, and I am getting the error from the title. I know for a fact that I am getting the password correct because I have 2 copies of the password written down and I have successfully created a signed apk multiple times on the machine the keystore was originally created on. I am wondering if I am getting this error that the file was tampered with or the password is incorrect because I cannot transfer the keystore files between computers? I certainly hope not because I will not have access to the original PC until the end of August. Any information is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have used key store many times on different machines.
It works perfectly without any problem.
As you told you noted down the password. Problem must be there with the key alias or you must be using some other jks file to generate the apk.

Lastly this might help 
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/forgot-keystore-passwordjks-file-you-can-still-recover-saswat-sahoo/